# Is this sentence syntactically correct: passive voice?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, passive-voice

Is this sentence syntactically correct and is it making any sense?

> "**The bias against introversion** has been **planted** so well that people often get concerned when children exhibit signs of limited socialization.

The main problem I am having is at the first phrase *bias against introversion*. Is it a valid phrase and then is the verb *planted* suitable for it?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please explain why you think *bias against introversion* couldn't be valid and why *planted* couldn't be suitable based on your research.

Comment: Well because "bias against introversion" is an unusual phrase. We usually used the word bias as in "He is biased in favor of X" or "bias towards  Y". It is just that I have never seen "bias against X" used somewhere, which was confusing to me.

Comment: And about "planted" it seems like someone else deliberately started a rumor or something but its not like that. The society itself went into favor of extroversion. So I was looking for a word which could fit the context (implying the fear towards introversion and also having an aggressive tune)

Comment: Perhaps you are only reading ancient English not modern English: it turns out that [*biased against* is now nearly twice as common](https://goo.gl/LIMwOz) — which makes perfect sense given the privative nature of bias in things like anti-discrimination laws and litigation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you have said is grammatically correct and reads okay. If you are looking for another way to word this sentence then maybe this is better.

"The bias towards extraversion is so ubiquitous that people often get concerned when children exhibit limited signs of socialization."

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. The question reads "Is this sentence syntactically correct?" and you answered that "it could be rephrased to ...". Your post doesn't answer the question. Please visit the help center and read the guidelines. This site is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this is grammatically correct---it is even a bit sophisticated!   The only thing I think might be changed is to add *where* it has been planted.  You might say  planted so well in society, for example.